# PHP POST Data to HTTPS Fail with 404 error! Even with (CURL, fopen and file_get_contents)

Tags: php, curl, post, fopen, file-get-contents

All my efforts failed! I can't POST data to `HTTPS` Even by using `CURL`, `fopen` and `file_get_contents`!
I always getting a `404` error!
However, when I leech the page using `GET` method it open with no errors!
But when I using `POST` method for that page with `its same URL` it always fail with a `404` error!

---

My PHP code :

```
<?php
###########################################
    function curl_fopen_getContents( $functionName='curl', $method='GET' ) 
    {
        $post_data = http_build_query(array( 'a'   => '1' ));
        $cookies   = 'a=1';

        $opts = array('http' => array(
            'method'     => strtoupper($method), 
            'header'     => 
                            "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                           ."Content-Length: " . strlen($post_data)."\r\n"
                           ."Cookie: $cookies\r\n",
            'content'    => $post_data,
            'timeout'    => 60
        ));
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        
        ///////////////////////////////////
        
        // you can decode it 
        $https_url = 'my_url_here';
        
        if( $functionName=='fopen' )
        {
            $result = fopen($https_url, 'r', false, $context); @fpassthru($result); @fclose($result);
        }
        elseif( $functionName=='file_get_contents' )
        {
            $result = file_get_contents($https_url, false, $context);
        }else{
            $result = curl_post($https_url, $method, $post_data, $cookies);
        }
        return $result;
    }

###########################################

    function curl_post( $https_url, $method='GET', $post_data='', $cookies='' ) 
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$https_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookies);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        
        if( strtoupper($method) !='GET' )
        {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
        }

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch); if(!$data){ $data=curl_error($ch); }
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
    
###########################################
    
    /*
        curl_fopen_getContents( $functionName, $method );
        
        $functionName = curl/fopen/file_get_contents
        $method       = GET/POST
    */
    echo curl_fopen_getContents( 'curl', 'GET' );
    
###########################################
?>
```

**Can you help please? Thanks Alot.**

Comment: Is the recieving page capable of HTTPS?

Comment: If your curl script is in an http page you can't call an https page. The server return a security error

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Yes I'm using HTTPS in my local server. AND The leeched page is using HTTPS too.

Comment: @Stefino76 - The leeched page is using HTTPS and I'm using HTTPS in my local server too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forget to pass some cookies..